# Get Current Time from Google using Google .NET client library?

Tags: c#, google-api-dotnet-client

Can I somehow request the current time from Google using the Google .NET Client library and C#?

I am migrating an older calendar application that syncs calendars using modification times.  I realize there is a new sync token method, but everything is already working using the modification time method for syncing.  My app remembers the last time it synced, so it uses this in future Events.List requests as the UpdatedMin value.  Currently it uses the local computer's time, and if this is off, it can miss events posted in this short time period.  Knowing the current time from Google will help here.

Comment: Can't you use the maximum timestamp of the objects you got last time instead?

Comment: Hmm, good point, I should have thought of that!  I didn't notice, but the Event.Updated value should give me what I need.  Thanks!